# How to use ternary operator to select function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator, function-call

The following snippet works

```
if (condition)
  node.addClass('myclass');
else
  node.removeClass('myclass');
```

but not this one

```
node[condition ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('myclass');
```

nor this one

```
(condition ? node.addClass : node.removeClass)('myclass');
```

If I test it with

```
console.log(node[condition ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']);
```

the browser prints that it's a function. Why can't I call it?

Comment: `node[condition ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('myclass');` worked fine for me... What is node exactly? I tested it with `$("body")[(1===1) ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("b")`

Comment: But seems like you are just reinventing toggleClass `node.toggleClass("foo", condition)`

Comment: @epascarello Thanks! Didn't know that function existed.

Answer (score 1):

It apparently works the way I gave my examples here. It doesn't work with one extra level of indirection.

```
function print(x) {
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}

print(condition ? node.addClass : node.removeClass)('myclass');
```

With this code, Chrome tells me this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

But I found out I can circumvent the problem by using `call` to pass the `node` as `this` to the function.

```
print(condition ? node.addClass : node.removeClass).call(node,'myclass');
```

Obviously, the right solution in this specific case is to use `toggleClass`, as @epascarello pointed out. I'm a little surprised that `this` gets lost in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Can be toggled with vanilla java script

```
node.classList.toggle('myclass',condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning the function to a variable.

```js
var twoLevel = {
  "foo" : {
    log: console.log
  },
  "bar" : {
    log: window.alert
  }
}

var fn = true ? twoLevel["foo"].log : twoLevel["bar"].log;
fn('test')
```